# Sensor data refreshing

Tags: java, android, sockets, client

So I made a communication with socket here (in Client.java ,  Override doInBackground, AsyncTask usage)

```
    String addr = "******";




    try {


        socket = new Socket(addr, 10100);

        while (socket.isConnected()) {

            Thread.sleep(200);



            socket.getOutputStream().write(sendData());
            socket.getOutputStream().flush();

        }  and so on..
```

And however, I created a constructor from main activity to Client do drag the informations from onSensorChanged (the Azimut, Roll and Pitch) as shown

```
public Client(Float a, Float b, Float c) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;

}
```

And I have to communicate with server to send him dynamic results from orientation sensor, and for sending i have that "sendData()" function for sending buffers that I made earlier. 
And all in all everything is working fine for my usage but there is one problem, the data outside the constructor does not refresh. So I'm communicating with server when I connect but im sending the same (first that he reads) azimut, roll and pitch over and over again. I tried so many things and still no clue how to get those informations out of Main Activity --> onSensorChanged to Client that it actually refreshes and send dynamic output. Any tips or help maybe? 
Thanks

Edit:

the onSensorChanged

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    Float a = event.values[0];
    BigDecimal result1;
    result1=round(a,2);


    Float b = event.values[2];
    if (b <= 5 && b >=-5){
        b = (float) 0;
    }
    b = (float) (b / 3.4);
    BigDecimal result2;
    result2 = round(b,2);


    Float c = event.values[1];
    if (c <= 5 && c >=-5){
        c = (float) 0;
    }

    c = (float) (c / 3.4);
    BigDecimal result3;
    result3 = round(c,2);

    Client myClient = new Client(a, b, c);
    myClient.execute();
```

And this is onData()

```
public byte[] sendData (){

byte[] buff = new byte[68];


  byte[] buff1 = intToBytes(1);
    byte[] buff2 = intToBytes(20);  // ** ROLL
    byte[] buff3 = intToBytes(21);  // ** PITCH
    byte[] buff4 = intToBytes(23); // ** AZIMUT
byte[] buff5 = intToBytes(5);
byte[] buff6 = intToBytes(6);
byte[] buff7 = intToBytes(7);
byte[] buff8 = intToBytes(8);
byte[] buff9 = intToBytes(9);
    byte[] buff10 = intToBytes(Math.round(c));
    byte[] buff11 = intToBytes(Math.round(b));
    byte[] buff12 = intToBytes(Math.round(a));
byte[] buff13 = intToBytes(13);
byte[] buff14 = intToBytes(14);
byte[] buff15 = intToBytes(15);
byte[] buff16 = intToBytes(16);
byte[] buff17 = intToBytes(17);


                System.arraycopy(buff1,0,buff,0,buff1.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff2,0,buff, 4,buff2.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff3,0,buff, 8,buff2.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff4,0,buff, 12,buff2.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff5,0,buff, 16,buff2.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff6,0,buff, 20,buff2.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff7,0,buff, 24,buff2.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff8,0,buff, 28,buff2.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff9,0,buff, 32,buff2.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff10,0,buff,36,buff2.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff11,0,buff,40,buff2.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff12,0,buff,44,buff2.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff13,0,buff,48,buff2.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff14,0,buff,52,buff2.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff15,0,buff,56,buff2.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff16,0,buff,60,buff2.length);
                System.arraycopy(buff17,0,buff,64,buff2.length);


    return buff;}
```

Comment: Show sendData() code. And show complete Client class code. And show all calls from MainActivity.

Comment: There is some more code @greenapps , need more?

Answer (score 0):

In every onSensorChange you create and start a new AsyncTask. Which is ok if the changes do not come often.

In your async task you create a new client socket which connects to te server and then sends it data. This is ok too. But after that you let that client resend the same data again and again. Why? So your async task never finishes.

You start a lot of new async tasks but they will never run. They will run sequentially. The next one will only start if the former finishes.

So close the client after you sent the data so doInBackground can finish and hence the asynctask.

After that the next one can run.

Comment: I understand what are u trying to say, I just can't turn your words in to a needed code, tried few things but didn't work. Can u be more specific what should I do? Thanks

Comment: `while (socket.isConnected())`. Remove the while condition as you will only execute that code once. Add socket.close();.